# Phone to computer without computer install

Tags: hardware

I want to display my phone screen on my computer so that it can be projected on a screen.

I am not allowed to install any software on the computer or alter any setting of the browser. I have tried various tools such as Airdroid, but they require software installation or Chrome additions (again, something which I can't use).

I don't really want to go down the road of dedicated cables for a particular phone because I will have to change my phone at some time.

I just thought: although I can't install any software, self-executing .jar files do seem to work on our current network.

Edit: I don't want to ROOT my phone if possible: it is too expensive to take the risk.

Comment: If your computer is running Windows 10 and supports Miracast, you can use the new pre-installed Connect app. Just start the app with your phone and computer connected to the same wireless network. Your computer should then show up on your phone in the list of devices you can cast to.

Comment: More info here: http://betanews.com/2016/08/07/windows-10-anniversary-update-cast-android/

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't Windows 10 -- it is a network version of Windows 7, I think. I'll look out for that if we ever get to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer that works: [Screen Mirror](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ajungg.screenmirror&hl=en_GB). When you run the app it generates a URL. You type that address (a little fiddly because it is all numbers) into a web browser and the page appears. You can alter the resolution and run it full screen in landscape mode to fill your computer screen. I didn't notice any lag (looking from the phone to the screen) and so any gap is too small to be any worry.

I was running the phone wirelessly and the computer through a wired network -- they are the same network, but both aren't wireless, something required by many products.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if how this works but have you tried this?  http://www.guidingtech.com/36734/mirror-android-display-pc-tv/

Comment: I can't install any software or extensions, including those for Chrome. Therefore the suggestions in this link(s) won't work. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like VNC for Android?  I have had great luck using VNC over the years. One example of a server app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc.
You can view, and indeed completely control, the computer running the VNC server by running the VNC viewer on your computer. This can either be an installed viewer (not possible in your case), as an uninstalled program like TightVNC or by running the Java applet that the server will serve up to your browser, if you have Java installed ov the viewing computer.

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow at work. TightVNC seems to be a bit dead (2014) but I will see whether it is okay on our network.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Perhaps another version of VNC might work (though I can't see how without installing software on the computer), but TightVNC didn't.

Answer (score 0):

How about streaming your phone screen to YouTube (with something like [Gusher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smamolot.gusher)), then watch it on your PC?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see this working as streaming is slow, particularly on the wireless network (which the phone would have to use).